# Facial expression detection

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, face-recognition

I am currently working on a project where I have to extract the facial expression of a user (only one user at a time) like sad or happy.

There are a lot of programs/APIs to do face detection but I did not find any one to do automatic expression recognition.

The best possibility I found so far:

-Using [Luxand FaceSDK](http://www.luxand.com/facesdk), which will give me access to 66 different points within the face, so I would still have to manually map them to expressions.

I used OpenCV for face detection earlier, which was working great, so If anyone has some tips on how to do it with OpenCV, that would be great!

Any programming language is welcome (Java preferred).

Some user on a [OpenCV board](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/Facial-expression-recognition-td3981566.html) suggested looking for AAM (active apereance models) and ASM (active shape models), but all I found were papers.

Comment: Fraunhofer Institute has built a library called [Shore](http://www.iis.fraunhofer.de/en/bf/bsy/produkte/shore.html) which is able to extract a users expression. But it is not free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for machine learning solutions. FaceSDK looks like a good feature extractor. I don't think that there will be an available library to solve your specific problem. Your best bet is to:

- choose a machine learning framework (SVM, PCA) with a java implementation
- take a serie of photos and label them yourself with the target expression (happy or sad)
- compute your model and test it

This involves some knowledge about machine learning.

Comment: Don't have any knowledge about machine learning so far but will look into the mentioned frameworks. Anyone tried ofxFaceTracker for that purpose?